# Admissible representations of an $\ell$-group are a (neutral) Tannakian category?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, p-adic-groups, smoothness, tannakian-category, admissible-representation

Let $G$ be an $\ell$-**group** in the sense of Bernstein/Zelevinsky (sometimes also called td-group), i.e. $G$ is a

- Hausdorff
- locally compact
- totally disconnected

topological group. Prominent examples are $\mathrm{GL}_n(F)$ of any non-archimedean local field $F$.

For (infinite) topological groups, a theory of general representations seems hopeless, so one generally restricts the study of representation theory to the study of continuous representations. For $G$ as above, these are the *smooth* representations. I consider only representations over $\mathbb{C}$.

Now, if $(\pi,V)$ is any smooth representation, its dual representation $(\pi^{\ast}, V^{\ast})$ is not necessarily smooth, so one considers instead its subrepresentation $(\hat{\pi}, \hat{V})$ of *smooth* linear forms, called the *contragredient representation*.

The smooth representation of $G$ should be a full subcategory of all representations of $G$, so in other words, the morphisms should not carry information about 'smoothness'.

If $(\pi,V)$ and $(\rho,W)$ are smooth representations, so is their tensor product $(\pi \otimes \rho,V \otimes W)$. The trivial representation $1$ is also smooth. So by standard linear algebra

$$
\mathrm{Hom}(W \otimes V, 1) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(W, V^{\ast}).
$$
In other words, the internal hom of *any* pair $(V,1)$ (in the category of *all* $G$-reps) should be $V^{\ast}$ and therefore should not exist in the category of smooth representations. Same should hold for *admissible* representations.

**Question:**

1.) Since the morphisms 'do not see smoothness', I expect
$$
\mathrm{Hom}(W \otimes V, 1) \not\cong \mathrm{Hom}(W, \hat{V}).
$$
Is it correct? Has anyone a nice (counter-)example?

2.) I might be mistaken, but the (non-)existence of internal Homs in the category of admissible representations (provided point 1. is true) is the only thing that prevents it from being a neutral Tannakian category. If 1.) is true, does the contragredient representation have a categorical interpretation?

Comment: I was probably mistaken, since $$\mathrm{Hom}(W, V^{\ast}) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(W, \hat{V})$$
as images of smooth representations should be smooth too: if I have a morphism $\Phi \colon V \to W$ with $V$ smooth and an element $\Phi(v)$, then $\mathrm{Stab}_G(\Phi(v))$ should contain $\mathrm{Stab}_G(v)$, and thus should be open as well. Thus, $\Phi(V) \subset (V^{\ast})^{\infty} = \hat{V}$. So indeed, if I restrict myself to the category of smooth representations, the internal hom of the pair $(V,1)$ should indeed be $\hat{V}$. Is it true?

Comment: 2) I think now that $\mathrm{Rep}^{\text{adm}}_{\mathbb{C}}(G)$ is *not* Tannakian, as it is lacking a tensor structure... If $V$ and $W$ are admissible, then $V \otimes W$ is not necessarily admissible, for instance take any quasi-char $\chi \colon G \to \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ of infinite order. Then $V = \bigoplus_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \chi^n$ is admissible, but $V \otimes V$ not as for example the trivial representation now appears infinitely many times.

Comment: Also, Tannakian Categories are 'those categories that arise as finite-dimensional reps' of some algebraic groups, and obviously admissible reps can be infinitely-dimensional.

Comment: Your example of $V=\bigoplus_{n\in\mathbb Z}\chi^n$ is not admissible. Indeed, $\ker(\chi)$ contains some compact open subgroup $K$, and the $K$-invariant vectors $V^K$ is infinite-dimensional.

Comment: @KentaSuzuki oh I see, that was sloppy from me.. thanks for the hint! There are unfortunately no chars. $K \to \mathbb{S}^1$ of infinite order, so any $\chi$ of $G$ restricts to $K$ as a finite-order one. Maybe I will come later to this, however I still think that the tensor product should not 'preserve admissibility'.

Comment: Take $G = \mathbb{G}_{\text{m}}(F) = F^{\times}$, and consider the family of characters $\chi_n \colon \mathcal{O}^{\times}_F \to \mathbb{S}^{1}$ with conductor $n$. Every $\chi_n$ extends uniquely to a character of $F^{\times}$ by $\chi(\pi) = 1$ where $\pi$ is a uniformizer of $F$. The rep. $V = \bigoplus_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \chi_n \oplus \chi^{-1}_{n}$ is admissible but $V \otimes V$ is not, as the trivial char. appears infinitely many times. One can easily extend this to $\mathrm{GL}_n(F)$.

Comment: That is a nice example, you probably want to consider the category of admissible, finite-length representations (in fact finite-length implies admissibility in most cases).